# Views pagers for anonymous users

Tags: 7, views

I've been trying to figure out why the pager element for views won't show up for anon users in Drupal 7. The following are the things I've tried to get them to show, cache clear, mess with the access param in the actual view, create a function that calls

```
drupal_static_reset('user_access');
drupal_static_reset('user_role_permissions');
```

Has anyone been able to solve this? I've searched Google for over an hour for a fix/explanation.

Comment: Those `drupal_static_reset()` calls just force Drupal to re-read the database tables, or invoke the hooks implemented by modules, to restore static values. They don't stop Drupal from applying permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If after running the permission checks drupal doesn't find enough items to fill your view it will not show the pager (for any user role). You should check why there aren't enough items for the view.
Did you check for the number of items on a page (in the view). Is the pager set to be on (in the view). There are chances that you forgot to check some of these settings. It happens.

Comment: It turns out its a bug with D7 views alpha, so I upgraded to beta3, and lost all of my views. Now have to rebuild them in the new, terrible UI